# Fetching data from URL which loads slow - missing few html tags in response

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, fetch-api

**Question 1:**

I tried using `fetch` to pull sector information of a stock from a table on a web page using a below code.

```
fetch('https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=3IINFOLTD')
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then((responseText) => {
        
        let document = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
        let table = document.getElementById('industryInfo');
        console.log(table);
});
```

however, the table tag is missing `tbody` with the above method, how do we wait until the entire page loads and the parse the document object from the response.

***below is the table tag from the response***

```
<table id="industryInfo" class="eq-series tbl-securityinfo cap-hide">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Macro-Economic Sector</th>
            <th>Sector</th>
            <th>Industry</th>
            <th>Basic Industry</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Question 2:**

While performing another task of similar nature, however, the website does not support `JSON`. How do we get the date in this case?

I have tried using `await` and `setTimeOut(function() {}, 10000)` nothing works.

Comment: That's all there is in the table with the id `"industryInfo"` when you look at `<https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=3IINFOLTD>` in the browser ...

Comment: That is only the thead, within tbody, you get sector and industry group information of the stock.

Comment: But if you look at the source html of your link in a browser (or editor), you will see that there actually is no `tbody` tag or additional data in the table with the id `industryInfo`. It is not there in the source, and this is why you are not getting it in the fetch, either, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code received by a GET request does not contain the `tbody`. That is generated by the JavaScript code on the page. You may want to instead do a fetch request to `https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=3IINFOLTD`.

```
fetch('https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=3IINFOLTD')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json.industryInfo.macro);
    console.log(json.industryInfo.sector);
    console.log(json.industryInfo.industry);
    console.log(json.industryInfo.basicIndustry);
});

// Outputs:
// "Information Technology"
// "Information Technology"
// "IT - Software"
// "Computers - Software & Consulting"
```

Comment: I am now trying to retrieve data from another site, which does not support `JSON`. Can you please tell me how to work around it?